# Why am I getting a "Run-Time Check Failure #2 - Stack around the variable 'pr' was corrupted" Error?

Tags: c++, matrix, random

It happens in void `numgeneratorinator(int ar[])` whenever I try to run run the program. The program itself is supposed to generate as many magic squares as the user needs, then checks how many of those are magic squares. I have that down however this number generator is not working with me and I keep getting the "Run-Time Check Failure #2 - Stack around the variable 'pr' was corrupted" Error. It seems to "work" when I change pr[9] to pr[10] but then when I print the matrix as a test it has a zero in it and after 1 run it results in the matrix having a really low number in it (like -83289).

```
#include <ctime>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip> //Used for printinator

void printinator(int a[][3]) //prints a matrix
{
    using namespace std;
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++)
            cout << fixed << setprecision(2) << setw(12) << a[i][j] << "  ";
        cout << endl;
    }
    cout << endl;
}

int Checkinator(int m[][3]) //https://www.codespeedy.com/how-to-check-the-given-matrix-is-magic-square-or-not-cpp/ This function checks to see if the created matrix is M A G I C A L
{
    int s1 = 0, s2 = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
        s1 += m[i][i];

    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
        s2 += m[i][3 - 1 - i];

    if (s1 != s2)
        return 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {

        int rs = 0;
        for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++)
            rs += m[i][j];

        if (rs != s1)
            return 0;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {

        int cs = 0;
        for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++)
            cs += m[j][i];

        if (cs != s1)
            return 1;
    }

    return true;
}

void numgeneratorinator(int ar[])
{
    int pr[9] = { 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9 };

    for (int i = 9; i > 1; --i)
    {
        int j = rand() % i;
        int temp = pr[i];
        pr[i] = pr[j];
        pr[j] = temp;
    }
    for (int i = 1; i < 9; ++i)
        ar[i] = pr[i];
}

int main()
{
    int tr;
    srand(time(0));
    char more = 'y';

    using namespace std;
    while (more == 'y' || more == 'Y')
    {
        cout << "\n\t\tHow many randomly generated matrix would you like to test? : ";
        cin >> tr;
        int res = 0;
        int ra = 0;
        int ar[9] = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9};
        int m[3][3] = { {0,0,0}, {0,0,0}, {0,0,0} };
        numgeneratorinator(ar);

            for (int p = 0; p < tr; p++)
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
                {
                    for (int k = 0; k < 3; k++)
                    {
                        m[i][k] = ar[ra++];
                        if (ra >= 10)
                            ra = 0;
                    }
                }
                if (Checkinator(m) == true)
                    res++;
            }
            cout << "\n\t\t\tThere are " << res << " magic squares after running " << tr << " times.\n";
            printinator(m); //This was used for testing purposes to ensure the random number generator was working
            cout << "\n\t\tWould you like to do another run? : ";
            cin >> more;
    }
}
```

Comment: Array indices begin at 0.

Comment: As this is a runtime error, it'll be a lot easier for us to help you debug if we can replicate your run. As such, can you please [edit] in what you're inputting for those `std::cin` statements?

Comment: Yea, it would be y or Y when it askes "\n\t\tWould you like to do another run? : " and up to 1000000 for when it asks for "\n\t\tHow many randomly generated matrix would you like to test? : ";

Comment: should be: `for (int i = 0; i < 9; ++i)
 {
  int j = rand() % (i+1);
`, in `numgeneratorinator` for one

Answer (score 0):

Because in the first for loop in the "numgeneratorinator" function you are writing on a memory region out of the range of the array called "pr", it is carried out in the first iteration with the first for loop because you have initialized the variable 'i' with the value 9 , while the "pr" array has 9 integers inside it but its accessibility range starts from 0 and ends at 8 so if i is equal to 9 you will corrupt a memory region not belonging to your array.
you should change the function like this:

```
void numgeneratorinator(int ar[])
{
    int pr[9] = { 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9 };

    for (int i = 8; i > 0; --i)
    {
        int j = rand() % i;
        int temp = pr[i];
        pr[i] = pr[j];
        pr[j] = temp;
    }
    for (int i = 0; i <= 8; ++i)
        ar[i] = pr[i];
}
```